# Is there PDO driver available for Google cloud spanner

Tags: pdo, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

We are trying to use google cloud spanner as our database storage and building our application on ZEND framework.

Just wanted to confirm if there is a PDO driver available ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is currently not a PDO driver for Cloud Spanner. The current choices are:

- [Official APIs and Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/api-libraries-overview)
- [JDBC drivers](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/jdbc-drivers)